# Finding remainder of division the sum of the given diapason and 987654321

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, optimization

Could you help me please ? I need a fast algorithm for calculating the following : the remainder of division the sum of the integers in the power from given range ( from **A** to **B** , 1 < **A**,**B** < 10^8 ) and 987654321;
For instance , if I have **A** = 10 , **B** = 15, I should calculate

```
((11^11) + (12^12) + (13^13) + (14^14) ) % 987654321
```

If I use this direct approach, it takes forever to calculate this. Is there a trick to calculate such kind of remainders?

Comment: Well I searched around a bit and it seems that a series such as "sum of n^n from a to b" seem to have no closed form or other useful properties, so I'm afraid you'll just be summing a bunch of powers. Of course, there is no reason to work with numbers larger than 987654321 throughout this, so it won't be *too* disastrous. E: if you get multiple queries, you could first precompute the prefix sum of the whole thing

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Not necessary. OP needs fast modular exponentiation, for which your largest register needs to be able to hold approx. the square of the modulus (here, 64 bits will do).

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful How this can run under 1 second if A = 1 and B = 10^8?

Comment: @PhamTrung Fast modular exponentiation on a machine with many logical cores.

Comment: exponation by squaring and taking the modulo after every step should do the trick easily. You can combine that with some kind of prime sieve to reuse earlier numbers and minimize the work.

Comment: From 1 to 1E8 takes about 8 seconds on my machine, are there no more tricks?

Comment: @harold Possibly use CRT to deal with smaller moduli (987654321 = 3^2×17^2×379721) and then judicious use of Euler's theorem and some other trick (TBD, which is why this is a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using fast modulo exponentiation, we can calculate `x^n` in `O(log(n))` time. In the worst case, if `A = 1 and B = n` where `n` can be upto `10^8`, then the total complexity will be around

```
log(2) + log(3) + log(4) + ... + log(n)
= log(n!)
~ n*log(n) - n + O(log(n))  (According to Striling's Approximation)
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

### Fast Modulo Exponentiation

This method is used to quickly calculate powers of the form `x^n` (in `O(log(n))` time).

It can be given as a recurrence relation:

```
x^n = (x^2)^(n/2)     if n is even
    = x*{(x^2)^(n/2)} if n is odd
```

So, essentially instead of multiplying `x` `n` times, we do the following:

```
    x = x^2;
    n = n/2;
```

time till we reach a trivial case, where `n = 1`.

Python code (with modulo for this case):

```
def fast(x, n, mod):
    if n == 1:
        return x % mod
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return fast(x**2 % mod, n/2, mod)
    else:
        return x*fast(x**2 % mod, (n-1)/2, mod) % mod
```